# Equivalence of complicated for and if condition in C++ to Scala

Tags: c++, scala

I need to write the following code in Scala (it is actually in C++). I have tried many ways but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
pair<HashClosed::const_iterator, HashClosed::const_iterator> p = 
                closedItemsets.equal_range(pos1->second.myTidSum);

            for ( HashClosed::const_iterator pos = p.first; pos != p.second; ++pos ) {
                 if ( pos->second.first == x->second.first ){}
```

Comment: Hi yosra, do you mean you are having trouble translating the given C++ code to Scala?

Comment: The posted code also doesn't do anything, just iterates over some data structures.  If you've "tried many ways", how about posting one of your attempts?

Comment: yeah , it is just a part of the code , I need just to know how to write the for condition and this if condition in scala

Comment: You said you tried many ways but they don't work. Can you please show what you have tried? You can update your question and provide more information by clicking on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thx everyone , I have find the solution , this code in c++ is written as following in scala

```
for (pos <-pos.get(p._1) if pos != p._2)
 {
    pos._2.toMap
    x._2.toMap
    if(pos._1 == x._1)
    {}
 }
```

Comment: `.toMap` doesn't do anything since you don't save the results. `pos._2` and `x._2` are unchanged.